# How can I disallow spaces in usernames?

Tags: users, database

Drupal allows spaces in usernames, is there an easy way to stop this?

Also, where is the documentation on the username specs? What are the min/max lengths and which characters are allowed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way to handle this is to implement [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) for the user sign up and edit forms and append your own validator to check for spaces in the username field.

As for the length of a username, the minimum is 1 character and the maximum is 60 - as per the [db schema](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.install/function/user_schema/7).

Answer (score 4):

A quick alternative is using Access rules, in drupal 6 you'll find them at yoursite.com/admin/user/rules for Drupal 7 I believe it was spun of to contrib as [User restrictions](http://drupal.org/project/user_restrictions)

All you need to do to disallow spaces in usernames is create a rule like this: `% %`